# Firebase cloud functions typescript ReferenceError: google is not defined

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-cloud-functions

I have a cloud function that make a request to google map api to get geocode location info from latlng. when i make the request it show that error in error in the logs `ReferenceError: google is not defined at /user_code/lib/file_name`
I don't what the reason behind that and i added the typed package to package.json file.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "tslint --project tsconfig.json",
    "build": "tsc",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@google/maps": "^0.4.6",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.30.10",
    "firebase-admin": "^5.12.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^1.0.4",
    "nodemailer": "^4.6.4",
    "twilio": "^3.16.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "tslint": "^5.10.0",
    "typescript": "^2.9.2"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

The function to load the location info

```
async function getAddressFromLatAndLang(location) {
  const maps = require('@google/maps')
  const googleMapsClient = maps.createClient({
    key: 'API_KEY',
    Promise: Promise
  });

  const latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude)
  const result = await googleMapsClient.geocode({ latlng: latlng }).asPromise()
  console.log(result)
}
```

Comment: is there google/maps npm package? can you please refer me to a url to check it out?

Comment: Yes and i added it

Comment: then perhaps u could try defining the const of maps above `getAddressFromLatAndLang` function on the main. Dynamic import / require might not be supported.

Comment: like this `const maps = google.maps` ?

Comment: `const maps = require('@google/maps')` above on the global before the `getAddressFromLatAndLang` function.

Comment: That's not the problem the problem in `new google.maps.LatLng` can't find google in runtime

Comment: I understand, but you are trying to require a module on runtime .. if this is not the problem then await it to initialize properly

Comment: OK i added it as an import in file and it;s working but i still have google error!!

Comment: dame error? how do u know it worked?

Comment: Sorry i edit the comment check it. OK i added it as as you said const above the function and it's working but i still have google error!!

Comment: same error as before?

Comment: Yes i get the same error in run time. the problem with @types/googlemaps but i couldn't know what's wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to use [NodeJs client library](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-js) for Google Maps web services.

Please note that `google.maps.LatLng` object is not defined in NodeJs library, this object is defined in Google Maps JavaScript API v3 that you can use on client side. In NodeJs client library according to github documentation you can use the following objects as a LatLng pair

> A latitude, longitude pair. The API methods accept either:
>
> - a two-item array of [latitude, longitude];
> - a comma-separated string;
> - an object with 'lat', 'lng' properties; or
> - an object with 'latitude', 'longitude' properties.

source: https://googlemaps.github.io/google-maps-services-js/docs/LatLng.html

As `location` in your function has the properties `latitude` and `longitude` you can use it directly in

```
 const result = await googleMapsClient.reverseGeocode({ latlng: location }).asPromise()
```

Note that for resolving coordinate to address you have to use a `reverseGeocode()` method. The `geocode()` method serves to resolve address string to coordinates.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your help i did that tries the location and the array solution but is give `invalidValueError: unexpected property "latlng"
    at Object.validator` i don't know why @xomena

Comment: i also try the string with , separator show me the same error

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice that, but you have to use `.reverseGeocode()` method in order to resolve latitude and longitude. I updated my answer. Please have a look at this method in documentation: https://googlemaps.github.io/google-maps-services-js/docs/GoogleMapsClient.html

Comment: But a question here why the new google.map.LatLng doesn't work and i added the types package?

Comment: Because `google.map.LatLng` doesn't form a part of the package that you included. The `google.map.LatLng` is defined in the client side [Google Maps JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial), but you are using a different server side NodeJs library that doesn't have this class.

Comment: I understand. anyway thank you for your help you saved my day